# Copy all .txt files from one object to another but in the same bucket using Java (Amazon S3)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my bucket named `myBucket` on **s3**, There are some files in a folder called `folder1`. I need to copy only the `.txt` files from `folder1` to `folder2`.
Note: Both `folder1` and `folder2` are present in the same bucket.

How can I do this using Java?

The hierarchy of both the folders are:

`myBucket/folder1`

`myBucket/folder2`

Comment: What have you done so far?  There are [great examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingJava.html) available to get you started.

Comment: As of now, I haven't done anything. I am completely new to this. The examples in the link provided by you copy a specific object when the object key is known to me. But I want to copy only the .txt files from one folder to another. The names of those .txt files can be anything and are not known to me.

Comment: Sure, but dig a little.  Combine [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#list-objects) for listing objects with the previous one.  List, filter for `.txt`, copy.

Answer (score 1):

S3 gives you the ability to list objects in a bucket with a certain prefix, in your case you can change the object name so that the prefix contains
the file type )for the moment not have suffix function :( )

Example name file:

```
TXT_file1.txt
```

```
ObjectListing objectList = s3client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                                .withBucketName(bucketName)
                                .withPrefix("TXT"));

for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
    s3client.copyObject(sourceBucketName, objectSummary.getKey(), estinationBucketName, objectSummary.getKey());
}
```

or...

you can get all and filter with the name of the files inside the for :) and you don't need to change the file names, but you have more get request in s3 and that implies more costs.